# Storing of photoreferences which are returned with place-details

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Can I store the photoreferences returned with place-details API (max 10 are returned) so that I can use them later directly to fetch the photos using places-photos API call? ToS states that we can't store anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, the [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license) state the following:

> 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.
>
> (a)  No Scraping. Customer will not extract, export, or otherwise
>   scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example,
>   Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost
>   Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download Google
>   Maps tiles, Street View images, geocodes, directions, distance matrix
>   results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and
>   time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or
>   user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech
>   services.
>
> (b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as
>   expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms.

And the [Specific Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/#5-places-api) say the following on what caching is allowed for Places:

> 5.4 Caching. Customer can temporarily cache latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) values from the Places API for up to 30 consecutive
>   calendar days, after which Customer must delete the cached latitude
>   and longitude values. Customer can cache Places API Place ID
>   (place_id) values, in accordance with the Places API Policies.

So it certainly doesn't look like you can store photo references. You may want to speak with a legal representative in any case.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: is there a way to contact google sales team regarding this? since places-photos is a separate API itself with unique query to fetch an image (and $7/1000 hits for the API), it doesn't make sense to call the details API everytime one wants an image (unless of course that's the intention)? It's similar to this - everytime we want the details of a place, we call the text-search API to get the place-id and then call the place-detail API with that place-id (or similarly, call the place-details API to get the map url and then call the map API to get the map) - but place-ids can be saved indefinitely

Comment: I don't think Google's Sales Team would be able to help you with this, you should discuss this with your legal counsel. Note that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#place_photo_requests) is clear on this being definitely intended; "photoreference — A string identifier that uniquely identifies a photo. Photo references are returned from either a Place Search or Place Details request.". If you were able to store photo references like with place IDs, the docs would mention it somewhere like they do place IDs. Instead, the ToS explicitly say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For scraping Google Maps place photos you can use third-party API such as [Google Maps Photos API](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-photos-api) from SerpApi. This is a paid API with a free plan that processes blocks and parses them on its backend.

To do this, we first need to find ["data_id"](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-photos-api#api-parameters-search-query-data-id) of all places for which we made a request:

```py
local_data_results = [
    (result['title'], result['data_id']) 
    for result in results['local_results']
]
```

Next, we make a new request to find all photos of places with pigmentation using `while` loop:

```py
while True:
    new_page_results = search.get_dict()
        
    if 'next' in new_page_results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(new_page_results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('next')).query)))
    else:
        break

    photos.extend(new_page_results['photos'])
```

Check full code with pagination in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-maps-place-photo-serpapi).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import os, json

# firslty extracting local results
params = {
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
    'api_key': '...',                       # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
    'engine': 'google_maps',                # SerpApi search engine 
    'q': 'Starbucks',                       # query
    'll': '@40.7455096,-74.0083012,15.1z',  # GPS coordinates
    'type': 'search',                       # list of results for the query
    'hl': 'en',                             # language
    'start': 0,                             # pagination
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)               # where data extraction happens on the backend
results = search.get_dict()                 # JSON -> Python dict

local_data_results = [
    (result['title'], result['data_id']) 
    for result in results['local_results']
]

photo_results = []

# secondly, extracting photos from returned data by local results
for title, data_id in local_data_results:
    params = {
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
        'api_key': '...',                   # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
        'engine': 'google_maps_photos',     # SerpApi search engine
        'hl': 'en',                         # language
        'data_id': data_id                  # place result
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    
    photos = []

    # pagination
    while True:
        new_page_results = search.get_dict()
        
        if 'next' in new_page_results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(new_page_results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('next')).query)))
        else:
            break

        photos.extend(new_page_results['photos'])
    
    photo_results.append({
        'title': title,
        'photos': photos
    })

print(json.dumps(photo_results, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
      "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOupV3HYP7Edx1hfZ4wQDXwAseYldLrcpLOMfXb=w203-h270-k-no",
      "image": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOupV3HYP7Edx1hfZ4wQDXwAseYldLrcpLOMfXb=w3024-h4032-k-no",
      "photo_meta_serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=AF1QipOupV3HYP7Edx1hfZ4wQDXwAseYldLrcpLOMfXb&engine=google_maps_photo_meta"
    },
    {
      "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMP6QTX3YtzENGSS-QnXIHK5A0vkBwHTN0J7ADX=w203-h360-k-no",
      "image": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMP6QTX3YtzENGSS-QnXIHK5A0vkBwHTN0J7ADX=w2432-h4320-k-no",
      "photo_meta_serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=AF1QipMP6QTX3YtzENGSS-QnXIHK5A0vkBwHTN0J7ADX&engine=google_maps_photo_meta"
    },
    other results ...
]
```

In this output, `photo_meta_serpapi_link` refers to additional information that SerpApi retrieves about the photo, like info about the user who took the photo, and the location and date.

Also you can read [How to Scrape Google Maps Place Photos using SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/blog/using-google-maps-photos-api-from-serpapi/) blog post if you need more code explanation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.