# how to get places images from google place api in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

```
photos = (

  {
                height = 2304;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/1152719XX951XXXX0531/photos\">XXX XX</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRaAAAAFectOxyAKTfvFyP6yIp24z8T6FAidRxYcAMEWYdpeijj6SckncfG9EpgOacw1LrPPrGYN_U6bSiR9D1DffgM";
                width = 4096;
            },           
)
```

- how to **get urls** of images or **download** images from **photo_reference**

Comment: Hi so do you get an error , what have you tried so far , have you enabled the API and have u taken the API KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) service to get the image corresponding to a `photo_reference` string.

Example request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

For iOS in swift, you can use the equivalent [Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/photos) service using a `placeID` instead. See sample code:

```
// Specify the place data types to return (in this case, just photos).
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.photos.rawValue))!

placesClient?.fetchPlace(fromPlaceID: "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE",
                         placeFields: fields,
                         sessionToken: nil, callback: {
  (place: GMSPlace?, error: Error?) in
  if let error = error {
    print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }
  if let place = place {
    // Get the metadata for the first photo in the place photo metadata list.
    let photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata = place.photos![0]

    // Call loadPlacePhoto to display the bitmap and attribution.
    self.placesClient?.loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: { (photo, error) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        print("Error loading photo metadata: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
      } else {
        // Display the first image and its attributions.
        self.imageView?.image = photo;
        self.lblText?.attributedText = photoMetadata.attributions;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Note that downloading the images returned from the API would violate Google's [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/). See related [Storing of photoreferences which are returned with place-details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533961/storing-of-photoreferences-which-are-returned-with-place-details)

Hope this helps!